# Sympy linsolve and solve giving different results

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I have a system of 52 equations with float coefficients (usually not rationals). This long list of equations is stored in variable `concrete_eqs`, and the list of unknowns (Lagrangians) in `lagran`. The system is linear.

Using `solve`, the solution would be:

```
result = solve(
              concrete_focs, lagran
              ,simplify = False 
              ,exclude = []

              )
```

Using `linsolve`, it would be:

```
linresult = list(linsolve(concrete_focs, lagran))
```

I checked the solution using `solve` by substituting back into the equations and it gives the correct result. Using `linsolve`, not only are the solutions different, but they are wrong: they do not solve the system when I substitute them back.

`linsolve` does not throw any errors. I transformed the system of equations into matrix form by using `linear_eq_to_matrix`, and the system has full rank. Since the unknowns are indexed variables, I also tried to solve the system with `linsolve` and only symbols, but this didn't solve the issue.

I would like to solve this linear system with `linsolve`, since it is much faster than `solve`, even for this simple system.

I tried to reproduce the issue in simpler problems, using indexed variables, but I got the correct result.

Any hints on why this may be happening? (I suspect it is because of the handling of the float irrational coefficients, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: A bug to do with float coefficients and linsolve was recently fixed but the fix is not yet released. Try using sympy master. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21520

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I tried installing sympy from Github master by using ```$ git clone https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git``` and then ```$ python setup.py install``` in the directory where I cloned the master branch. My version is ```'1.9.dev'```. However, the same error persists: ```linsolve``` and ```solve``` are still giving different results. If I could tell ```solve``` that the system is linear, perhaps there could be performance gains, but as far as I know, you can't do that. ```solve``` seems too slow for this simple problem...

Comment: This could be a bug in `linsolve`. I suggest opening an issue with sympy on GitHub. It won't be possible to investigate this further without seeing the actual equations though.

Comment: Thanks. I will open an issue when I am able to. I can show the equations too, even though they are somewhat burdensome.