# What is the best way to construct, and then solve quickly a system of linear equations in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, equation-solving, linear-equation

Suppose I have a big system of linear equations:

```
X_1*a_11 + X_2*a_21 + ... + X_n*a_n1 = b_1
.
.
.
X_1*a_1m + X_2*a_2m + ... + X_n*anm = b_m
```

The dimensions `n` and `m` are fixed (are not symbolic).
I can find and plug the values of each coefficient `a_ij`, and I want to solve for all `X_i`. If I could write these in matrix form, I could use `numpy.linalg.solve` for example. However, I don't want to manually construct this matrix with the coefficient. Is there an efficient way to convert this system of equations to a matrix and solve it with `numpy.linalg.solve`?

I know I could define all X as Sympy symbols, create a list of equations and use, for example, Sympy's `linear_eq_to_matrix` to transform this list of symbolic equations into a symbolic matrix. I could also just use Sympy's  `solve` or `linsolve` using this list of equations and a list of unknowns, but I think there is a loss of performance involved in comparison to using Numpy.

What would be the best approach to tackle this?

### Edit

A very simple example

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

dim = 4
# Getting coefficients
a = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,dim)) 
b = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,))
# Numerical array for solutions
n_X = np.empty(shape = (2,))
n_Y = np.empty(shape = (2,))

# Defining unknowns
s_X_1 = Symbol('X_1')
s_Y_1 = Symbol('Y_1')
s_X_2 = Symbol('X_2')
s_Y_2 = Symbol('Y_2')

#Defining equations
eq1 = s_X_1*a[0,0] + s_Y_1*a[1,0] + s_X_2*a[2,0] + s_Y_2*a[3,0]- b[0]
eq2 = s_X_1*a[0,1] + s_Y_1*a[1,1] + s_X_2*a[2,1] + s_Y_2*a[3,1]- b[1]
eq3 = s_X_1*a[0,2] + s_Y_1*a[1,2] + s_X_2*a[2,2] + s_Y_2*a[3,2]- b[2]
eq4 = s_X_1*a[0,3] + s_Y_1*a[1,3] + s_X_2*a[2,3] + s_Y_2*a[3,3]- b[3]

unknowns = [s_X_1, s_X_2] + [s_Y_1, s_Y_2]
eqs = [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4]
# Transforming the system into matrix form and solving
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqs, unknowns)
result = list(linsolve((A,b), unknowns))[0]
# Filling the numerical array with the sympy result
n_X[0] = result[unknowns.index(s_X_1)]
n_X[1] = result[unknowns.index(s_X_2)]
n_Y[0] = result[unknowns.index(s_Y_1)]
n_Y[1] = result[unknowns.index(s_Y_2)]
```

However, if I already had `A` and `B`, I could simply do:

```
A_num = np.array(A).astype(np.float64)
b_num = np.array(b).astype(np.float64)
result_num = np.linalg.solve(A_num, b_num)
```

Measuring performance:

```
%%timeit -r 100 -n 100
result_sym = list(linsolve((A,b), unknowns))[0]
1.95 ms ± 285 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -r 100 -n 100
result_num = np.linalg.solve(A_num, b_num)
The slowest run took 9.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
15.5 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -r 100 -n 100
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqs, unknowns)
A_num = np.array(A).astype(np.float64)
b_num = np.array(b).astype(np.float64)
441 µs ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, the sympy solution is orders of magnitude slower than the numpy solution. Likewise, the operation of transforming our numerical system into matrix form and then converting it to a numpy array to use `numpy.linalg.solve` is much slower than solving the system itself!

Comment: I don't get what data you have, exactly. If the a_ij aren't already stored in a matrix, where are they?

Comment: To *solve quickly*, you would exactly use `numpy.linalg.solve`. You'll have to specify exactly what kind of data (float, string, text file, code, on paper?) you have your linear system's terms in, maybe there's a *program* that can make the necessary matrix. You already mentioned one way people do it: `linear_eq_to_matrix`

Comment: @AnneAunyme I can get the `a_ij` for each separate equation solving other equations that don't matter to this specific problem. But with that information, it doesn't follow (at least for me) that I can write easily the system in the form Ax = b.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I can compute all coefficients as floats. For now, the `X` are all Sympy symbolic. I am having trouble with the mixed symbolic-numeric approach: `linsolve` is not solving the equations correctly, even though it is relatively fast. `solve` solves the system correctly but it is too slow (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911190/sympy-linsolve-and-solve-giving-different-results)). Besides, the Sympy `subs` operation repeteadly slows everything. I would like to solve everything numerical, to make use of numpy vectorization, numba and parallelization.

Comment: You got a lot of ideas but unless you provide code examples in the post that people can paste and run themselves, it's gonna be hard for people to help you. You shouldn't paste your entire code, but just a small example (maybe 3 x 3 matrix system) that shows how you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: For one thing, I would normally think that if you can solve for all `a_ij`, you would already have all the information you need to construct your NumPy array matrix, no need to write a linear system in code like in the example. But I can't be sure because you didn't provide a minimum working example (MWE) code.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I edited with code for a simple example.
I do have all the __information__ needed to construct the numpy array matrix. However, the dimension of the problem is big, each equation is different from the other, and to input this information I would have to extract all the coefficients associated with each unknown, which seems infeasible without symbolic computation (slow, no numba). Maybe there's no way of running away from sympy here, but I was wondering if there is a way that I didn't think of.

Comment: Not a comment about OP's post, but rather @BatWannaBe's comments.  Just wanted to say great job leading OP to improve their questions with gentle prods.  I'm just seeing the text for the first time now, and it's in a very answerable form, largely due to the help you gave.  Kudos to you!

Comment: The code example is definitely helpful, it sheds a lot of light onto what you know and have tried. But my question about where you get your coefficients isn't quite answered. You construct random NumPy arrays `a` and `b` for your MWE: those are already ready to go into `scipy.linalg.solve`. Writing `a[0,0]`, `a[0,1]`, ... in a system of SymPy equations is just as "manual" as just typing in coefficient values; you'll have to rewrite everything if just one more variable or equation is thrown in.

Comment: My current suspicion is that what you actually have is a several non-0 coefficient values for which you know subscripts, so each data point would be (a_jk : float, j : int, k :int). And obviously you don't want to hand-write all the 0s in a matrix or linear system. That's fine, actually. You can find out how big your system is from the biggest i and j values, construct a 0s matrix with `np.zeros`, and fill in the nonzero coefficients one by one `a[j-1, k-1] = a_ij` in a for-loop. Definitely better than by hand.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I see your point now. However, iff the system is sparse (lots of zeros) and has many unknowns (my case), it would be way harder to find all nonzero coefficients for every equation, input it in every row. Using sympy, I got the `a` by using `subs` on a list of symbolic equations, in such a way that the coefficients would be computed easily for me (although costly computationally). In other words, these `a` are already computed in my list of symbolic equations, but I don't know what is the unknown that they refer to.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Your solution with `np.zeros` and filling the coefficients as you explained seems promising. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should make a MWE showing you getting `a` by `sub`-ing a list of symbolic equations. I'm not actually that well-versed in SymPy, but just so we're on the same page, `scipy.linalg.solve` can't do symbolic math. It only knows fast math on floats, not symbols for unknown coefficient values, and it's not valid to substitute an unknown value with a 0. You can guarantee that you get all the nonzero coefficients as known floats, right?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Yes, I know `scipy.linalg.solve` and `numpy.linalg.solve` can't do symbolic math. What happens in my algorithm is: everything begins symbolic, and eventually the symbols are substituted by concrete values (floats or ints), so that at the end I am with a linear system of concrete values. I can guarantee that I get all nonzero coefficients as floats in the end.

Comment: Several points: 1. I think it would be best to discuss this in a sympy issue on GitHub because SO is too limited (I only get 500 characters!) and also there are probably things that can be improved in sympy. 2. Many things in sympy are faster if you install gmpy2. 3. There have been recent improvements to linsolve so I suggest using latest sympy or actually current master. 4. I find it hard to believe that 2ms is significant compared to whatever symbolic calculations lead up to the point (a realistic size example would be bettter).

Comment: 5. Don't read too much into timeit numbers. Actual times for real problems are what matters. Calling np.linalg.solve once I find that it takes 300us. 6. There's no reason to think that the cost of e.g. linear_eq_to_matrix would scale in the same way as linalg.solve for larger systems. 7. Timings can be very different for dense vs sparse systems so if your actual problem is sparse don't benchmark with dense systems. 8. There really isn't enough space here to discuss this properly so GitHub is a better place.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin [1]Thank you very much for the comments again. I tried previously using `linsolve` from Github master following your suggestion from another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911190/sympy-linsolve-and-solve-giving-different-results). I will look into gmpy2, thanks for the suggestion. A realistic example would be a sparse system in the order 450x450 to 800x800 (the size of the final problem is unknown to me by now). The iterations using `solve` (since `linsolve` is giving me wrong results for some reason) are about 30s to solve the simplest version of the problem

Comment: @OscarBenjamin [2]... far too slow. I know I should open a Github issue to investigate  the odd behavior from `solve`  further, and I intend to in the future, but I am afraid I won't be able to right now. My problem is indeed sparse, so I think this will play an important role. How can we proceed with this present discussion in Github?

Comment: You can open a new issue here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues. You will still need to provide more detail than you have in either of these SO questions though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236661/discussion-between-econbernardo-and-oscar-benjamin).

Comment: I don't think that the chat helps. This is still too limited a forum and without a clear demonstration of what you're doing there isn't much I can say. SO is okay for a quick question and answer but you haven't provided the information needed for a quick answer.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I will open an issue in Github, and try to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am assuming that your input is a system of symbolic equations where all the coefficients and independent terms are floating point numbers, like the one you show in the MWE, but much bigger.

In that case, maybe this method could be useful for you.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

dim = 4
# Getting coefficients
a = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,dim))
b = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,))
# Numerical array for solutions
n_X = np.empty(shape = (2,))
n_Y = np.empty(shape = (2,))

# Defining unknowns

s_X_1 = Symbol('X_1')
s_Y_1 = Symbol('Y_1')
s_X_2 = Symbol('X_2')
s_Y_2 = Symbol('Y_2')

#Defining equations
eq1 = s_X_1*a[0,0] + s_Y_1*a[1,0] + s_X_2*a[2,0] + s_Y_2*a[3,0] - b[0]
eq2 = s_X_1*a[0,1] + s_Y_1*0 + s_X_2*a[2,1] + s_Y_2*a[3,1]- b[1]
eq3 = s_X_1*a[0,2] + s_Y_1*a[1,2] + s_X_2*a[2,2] + s_Y_2*a[3,2]- b[2]
eq4 = s_X_1*a[0,3] + s_Y_1*a[1,3] + s_X_2*0 + s_Y_2*a[3,3]- b[3]

# List of equations and unknowns

eqs = [eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4]
unknowns = ["X_1","Y_1","X_2","Y_2"]

b = []                                      # Independent terms
A = []                                      # Coefficients matrix

for eq in eqs:

    a = [0.]*len(unknowns)                  # List of coefficients for equation

    # Equation to list of strings

    l = str(eq).strip().replace(" + ","*").replace(" - ","*-").split("*")

    # Dictionary where keys are variables and values coefficients ( X_1: a[0,0] )

    dic = {l[i+1]:l[i] for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2)}
    for key in dic:
        a[unknowns.index(key)] = float(dic[key])

    # Add elements to A and b

    b.append(float(l[-1]))
    A.append(a)

# Solving the system

x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

It basically transforms each equation to a string and then creates a dictionary where keys are unknowns and values are coefficients, so they can be easily identified.

To check if the method is faster than just using sympy, I've written a program that allows me to create this same example but with a big system and, apart from the fact that it needs a lot of time to read all the symbolic equations (which shouldn't be a problem if you are already using them), it creates A and b and calculates the solution in about 3 seconds for a 100x100 case (sympy spends about 13s).

I paste the code here in case you want to check it by yourself.

```
with open("out.py","w") as file:

    dim = 100

    file.write("from sympy import * \n")
    file.write("import time\n")
    file.write("import numpy as np \n\n")


    for i in range(0,dim):

        file.write('s_X_%d = symbols("X_%d")\n'%(i+1,i+1))

    file.write("\n")
    file.write("dim = %d \n\n"%dim)

    file.write("a = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,dim))\n")
    file.write("b = np.random.uniform(low = -3, high = 3, size= (dim,))\n\n")

    for i in range(dim):
        s = "eq%d = "%(i+1)
        for j in range(dim):

            s += " + s_X_%d*a[%d,%d]"%(j+1,j,i)

        s += " - b[%d]\n"%i
        file.write(s)

    st = "eqs = [eq1"
    #uk = 'unknowns = [s_X_1'                           # Uncomment for sympy
    uk = 'unknowns = ["X_1"'                            # Uncomment for my method

    for i in range(2,dim+1):
        st += ",eq%d"%i
        uk += ',"X_%d"'%i                               # Uncomment for my method
        #uk += ',s_X_%d'%i                              # Uncomment for sympy

    file.write("\n")
    file.write(st + "]\n")
    file.write(uk + "]\n")

    # This uses sympy
    """
    file.write("print('Starts running')\n")
    file.write("t0 = time.time()\n\n")
    file.write('A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqs, unknowns)\n')
    file.write('result = list(linsolve((A,b), unknowns))[0]\n')
    file.write('n_X = np.empty(shape = (%d,))\n\n'%dim)

    for i in range(dim):
        file.write('n_X[%d] = result[unknowns.index(s_X_%d)]\n'%(i,i+1))

    file.write('print("Elapsed time:",time.time() - t0)')
    """
    # This uses my method
    file.write("\nb = []\nA = []\n")
    file.write('print("Starts running")\nt0 = time.time()\n')
    file.write("for eq in eqs:\n\n")
    file.write("\ta = [0]*len(unknowns)\n")
    file.write('\tl = str(eq).strip().replace(" + ","*").replace(" - ","*-").split("*")\n')
    file.write('\tdic = {l[i+1]:l[i] for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2)}\n\tfor key in dic:\n')
    file.write('\t\ta[unknowns.index(key)] = float(dic[key])\n')
    file.write('\tb.append(float(l[-1]))\n\tA.append(a)\n')
    file.write('x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)\n')
    file.write('\nprint("Elapsed time:",time.time() - t0)')
```

This is my first answer here, so hope it was useful!

**EDIT**

I realised that you don't actually need to use a dictionary to store coefficient values. It could be done this way.

```
# Old code
dic = {l[i+1]:l[i] for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2)}
for key in dic:
    a[unknowns.index(key)] = float(dic[key])

# New code
for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2):
    a[unknowns.index(l[i+1])] = float(l[i])
```

Maybe it won't help to save a lot of time, but it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think it may be a good alternative. I think what may be slowing this are all these string operations, but the 13s to 3s improvement is substantial.

Comment: I agree with that, but I just couldn't find a better way to get all the coefficients out of the symbolic equations without missing information about their position.